# Add a xml configuration to render a view directly without using a controller

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am trying to implement Spring security authentication in my web application.
I found this in a book. The config in my security.xml:

```
<http ...>
…
<form-login login-page="/login/form"
login-processing-url="/login"
username-parameter="username"
password-parameter="password"
authentication-failure-url="/login/form?error"/>
</http>
```

To make Spring MVC aware of the new URL this is put in WebMvcConfig.java:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.
ViewControllerRegistry;
...
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry){
registry.addViewController("/login/form")
.setViewName("login");
}
...
}
```

I was wondering how to implement this if I am using an xml app-config file, instead of the java config file. This is because I am using xml config mostly in my app.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the [Configuring View Controllers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-view-controller) section of Spring docs

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/login/form" view-name="login"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks I read the same book with you, but if I use WebMvcConfig.java to add the new URL I got 404 "login/form" is not available error. However, if I use the XML config, it work.

Comment: It worked both ways for me. What was your error log?